# Combining data from rows into a column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, combinations

I am trying to combine data in a spreadsheet. I have three columns in my original spreadsheet.

The first column is a "key" column, with student names in it.
The second column is a class period column, with numbers from 1 - 6 in it.
The third column is the teacher's name for that class period.

The data is currently in six entries for each student.

Student Name 1, Class 1, Teacher Name 1

Student Name 1, Class 2, Teacher Name 2

Student Name 1, Class 3, Teacher Name 3 and so on.

I'm looking for a way to combine this data to have:

Student Name 1, Teacher Name 1, Teacher Name 2, Teacher Name 3

Student Name 2, Teacher Name 1, Teacher Name 2, Teacher Name 3

I'm capable of using formulas--I just don't know what this particular type of data combination would be called to help me Google the right  thing.

I've tried importrange, but I keep getting errors AND this is a huge spreadsheet, so I'm thinking that might not be the best way to go.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following formula-

```
=HSTACK(UNIQUE(A2:A7),MAP(UNIQUE(A2:A7),LAMBDA(x,TOROW(FILTER(C2:C7,A2:A7=x)))))
```

[image]